# Divisor of degree g on a genus g curve with 1 dimensional global section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

When I read the proof of theorem of cube, there is a claim saying that on a genus g curve C, there is always a divisor $D=\sum_{i=1}^{g}P_i$ such that $H^0(C,\Omega_C^{1}\otimes \mathcal{O}(-D))=0$. By Riemann-Roch, this is equivalent to requiring such a  $D$ satisfying $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}(D))=1$. How do I find such a $D$?

Comment: If $Z$ is a divisor with $H^0(C,O(Z))\neq 0$, then for a general point $P$, $h^0(C,O(Z-P))=h^0(C,O(Z))-1$. Starting with $\Omega^1_C$ inductively find the $P_i$'s.

Comment: If you think of the canonical embedding of the curve, your condition is saying that the points do not lie on a hyperplane. So, since the curve itself does not lie on a hyperplane, it is clear that you can choose $g$ points with the required property.